# How to not populate contents inside a given div

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
<div id = "container1" >
<div id = "x1" />
<div id = "x2" />
<div id = "x3" />
</div>

<div id = "container2" >
<div id = "Y1" />
<div id = "Y2" />
<div id = "Y3" />
</div>

<div id = "container3" >
<div id = "Z1" />
<div id = "Z2" />
</div>
</body>

$('body div').each(function(i) {
if($(this).attr('id')!='container2') {  //This is only for div container2 & not for elements inside it
    console.log(i);
}
});
```

I don't want the elements within a particular div say container2 to be populated how can this be done..
in above code it populates the div's inside container2

Comment: What do you actually mean by populate data? Do you want to hide the contents of that particular div? or empty the data of that div?

Comment: There can be number of ways, add another check in your _if_ condition that will check whether inner divs' parent is not container2. This is not tested: `$(this).parent().attr('id')!='container2'`

Comment: @ San : i'm actually emptying the div

Comment: sure.. thanks @Coder wil chk it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alter your selector to exclude what you don't want:

exclude 'container2': `$('body div[id!="container2"]')`

exclude all div's with container in it: `$('body div').not('[id*="container"]')`

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('body div').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).attr('id')!='container2') {  
        console.log($(this).clone().empty());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work out for you:

```
$('body div').each(function(i) {
 if($(this).attr('id').indexOf("container") !== -1) {  
   //this is a container element. It could be ANY container.

   //you could check for which container like         
   $(this).attr('id')//returns the container id

   //if you want its children 
   $(this).children();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like such ->

```
$(function(){
  $('body div').each(function(i,value) {
    if($(value).attr('id') == 'container2') {  //This is only for div container2 & not for elements inside it
      console.log(i);
    }else{
   console.log('these are not the container!'); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('body div').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'container2' || $(this).parent().attr('id') == 'container2' ) 
     {  
      //not showing any thing 
     }
     else
     { 
         alert(($(this).html());
     }
  });
});
```